# combine multiple Mono<List<Item>> into one

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm currently working on a project that involves a bit of reactive programming.

I have 4 different reactive repositories from which I get 4 different `Mono<List<SomeType>>` in return respectively.
The goal is to **combine them into a single `Mono<List<GeneralType>>`** in order to incorporate that into a custom Response to return within a `ResponseEntity.ok()`. I have already taken care of creating a `GeneralType` and was successful in converting a single `Mono<List<SomeType>>`, however, made no further progress.

All repositories have a similar signature:

```
public Mono<List<SomeType>> findAllByUserId(UUID userId)
```

The field in my Response that incorporates all different lists as a single one:

```
private Mono<List<GeneralType>> items;
```

What my method looks like so far:

```
public Mono<List<GeneralType>> combineMonos(UUID userId) {
    Mono<List<GeneralType>> combo1 = reactiveRepository.findAllByUserId(userId)
        .map(list -> list.stream()
            .map(GeneralType::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return combo1; // works just fine
}
```

All the other lists have pretty much the same approach, but putting them together into a single Mono<List> is a problem.

I've tried the following:

```
return Flux.merge(combo1.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable), combo2.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)).collectList();
```

But with that, the IDE urges to change the return type to `Flux<Object>`.
Also, some lists can be empty, so I'm not sure if `zip()` is an option here. I've read that it will return everything as *empty* if at least a single result is empty.

So the question is **how can that be done in an efficient way without *block()* everywhere?**

Comment: Empty mono is different from mono of empty list. mono can continue `zip` if it has a value of empty list. But mono cannot continue `zip` if it has empty value. You can try `zip()` operator to combine all `Mono` into one.

Comment: @shafayathossain Thanks a lot for the clarification! I had a feeling I misunderstood something somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Merge** connects to all the data sources eagerly. So as and when data is emitted from the any of the sources, it would be passed to the downstream pipeline. Order in the resulting list is based on when the item was emitted.

**Zip** method collects the data from sources and places them inside an object (Tuple – something like a box) and passes to the downstream. Zip will work as long as all the sources emit data. Any of the sources completes/throws error, it will stop.

---

I assumed your individual methods are working fine. Your question is related to merging the results into a single list.

```
private Mono<List<String>> getList1(){
    return Mono.just(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
}

private Mono<List<String>> getList2(){
    return Mono.just(Collections.emptyList());
}

private Mono<List<String>> getList3(){
    return Mono.just(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
}


    Flux.merge(getList1(), getList2(), getList3())
            .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(System.out::println);  // [a, b, c, A, B, C]
```

---

Reference:
http://www.vinsguru.com/reactive-programming-reactor-combining-multiple-sources-of-flux-mono/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it! Unfortunately, I will only be able to test it tomorrow, however, I have a strong feeling that will do the trick:)
Btw, I had your website already open before even posting the question. Thanks for the info there as well - really helpful!

Comment: @cypherman, I think I misunderstood your question. Merge and Zip for completely 2 different use cases. Merge is combining 2 lists into a single list. Zip produces a pair of objects. I thought you wanted to merge the responses. Check the other answer as well. Please accept that as answer if you think that you needed zip.

Comment: I do need to merge the responses. The problem is that I have **4 different** `Mono<List<GeneralType>>` and I need to combine them together into a single `Mono<List<GeneralType>>` to return.

Answer (score 1):

A `Mono::zip` will asynchronously combine the three publishers together which I think is the best solution.

Otherwise it is a pretty straightforward problem:

```
Mono<List<String>> m1 = Mono.just(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"}));
Mono<List<Character>> m2 = Mono.just(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'a', 'b', 'c'}));
Mono<List<Integer>> m3 = Mono.just(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));
Mono.zip(m1, m2, m3)
        .map(tuple3->{
                List<Combined> c = new ArrayList<>();
                int size = tuple3.getT1().size();
                for ( int i=0; i < size; ++i ) {
                    c.add(new Combined(tuple3.getT1().get(i), tuple3.getT2().get(i), tuple3.getT3().get(i)));
                }
                return c;
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
// [Combined(s=A, c=a, i=1), Combined(s=B, c=b, i=2), Combined(s=C, c=c, i=3)]
```

For completeness sake:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Combined {
    String s;
    Character c;
    Integer i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and an example! I understand now that `Mono::zip` will combine them, but the example didn't make it clear for me how to combine already existing `Mono<List<GeneralType>>` into a single one.